# Подскажите как правильно реализовать календарь?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js, calendar, google-calendar

[image]

Вот я тут сверстал простенький интерфейс календаря но не могу сообразить как реализовать переключение месяцев чисел и т.д (не обращайте внимание на то что дней шесть это временное решение сделал через флексы,переделаю на гриды наверное!) Может кто нибудь указать направление куда мне двигаться?(Только не матом!)))) возможно кто то уже реализовывал такое! желательно на нативном js так как я учусь еще! но было бы интересно почитать и о способах через сторонние плагины и фреймворки!

Comment: код выкладывать не стал так как там чистая верстка без кода js! потому не вижу смысла но если понадобится могу скинуть!))

Comment: Используйте `<input type='date' onchange='console.log(this.value)'/>` [Календарь в input для ввода даты](https://it-blog.ru/html/kalendar-dlya-vvoda-daty-v-input/) Должно значительно облегчить реализацию переключения месяцев чисел и т.д.